# The following handlers are available to decode the pixel data however they are missing required dependencies: GDCM (req. ), pylibjpeg (req. )

Tags: python

How do I fix this problem?
I  have installed pylibjpeg pylibjpeg-libjpeg pydicom ,python-gdcm (pydicom, pylibjpeg, pylibjpeg-libjpeg, pylibjpeg-openjpeg)

And still, the problem occurs.

```
    dir = r"D:\\Projects\\Kaggle\\RSNA\\train_images\\" + train['StudyInstanceUID'][i]
    count = listDir(dir)
    print(count)
    for j in range(1,count+1):

        sec = str(j) +".dcm"
        image_path= os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dir,sec))
        # image_path = r"D:\\Projects\\Kaggle\\RSNA\\train_images\\"+train['StudyInstanceUID'][i]+'\\'+ 
        ds = dicom.dcmread(image_path)
        ds.PhotometricInterpretation = 'YBR_FULL'
        pixel_array_numpy = ds.pixel_array 
        image_format = '.jpg' 
        image_path = image_path.replace('.dcm', image_format)

        cv2.imwrite(image_path, pixel_array_numpy)

def listDir(dir):
    count = 0 
    FileName = os.listdir(dir)
    return len(FileName)
```

Photo for example: https://github.com/maxmelichov/photo/blob/main/1.dcm
I'm running python 3.10.5 64 bit

Full RuntimeError

````
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
d:\Projects\Kaggle\RSNA\1.ipynb Cell 9 in <cell line: 1>()
     10 ds = dicom.dcmread(image_path)
     11 ds.PhotometricInterpretation = 'YBR_FULL'
---> 12 pixel_array_numpy = ds.pixel_array
     13 image_format = '.jpg' 
     14 image_path = image_path.replace('.dcm', image_format)

File c:\Users\maxme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pydicom\dataset.py:1887, in Dataset.pixel_array(self)
   1872 @property
   1873 def pixel_array(self) -> "numpy.ndarray":
   1874     """Return the pixel data as a :class:`numpy.ndarray`.
   1875 
   1876     .. versionchanged:: 1.4
   (...)
   1885         :class:`numpy.ndarray`.
   1886     """
-> 1887     self.convert_pixel_data()
   1888     return cast("numpy.ndarray", self._pixel_array)

File c:\Users\maxme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pydicom\dataset.py:1444, in Dataset.convert_pixel_data(self, handler_name)
   1442     self._convert_pixel_data_using_handler(handler_name)
   1443 else:
-> 1444     self._convert_pixel_data_without_handler()

File c:\Users\maxme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pydicom\dataset.py:1531, in Dataset._convert_pixel_data_without_handler(self)
   1525         names = [hh_deps[name][1] for name in missing]
   1526         pkg_msg.append(
   1527             f"{hh.HANDLER_NAME} "
   1528             f"(req. {', '.join(names)})"
   1529         )
-> 1531     raise RuntimeError(msg + ', '.join(pkg_msg))
   1533 last_exception = None
   1534 for handler in available_handlers:

RuntimeError: The following handlers are available to decode the pixel data however they are missing required dependencies: GDCM (req. ), pylibjpeg (req. )```
````

Comment: I restarted the kernel and if it still doesn't work try to reinstall pylibjpeg,pylibjpeg_libjpeg,python_gdcm